# HTML form action

Tags: asp.net

I need to create a website and add a guest book, email registration, and confirmation (to user + back from user). I've already made the website and also the registration page using forms. I'm having a trouble with the action. I would like to know how I can get the registration and confirmation sent. I did a research online and found out I can use asp to do that. I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 with the .NET framework. How do I write a simple asp script for the form submission. Do I need to use ASP or can i do it some other way. Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get started with ASP.NET have a look through some examples at  [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp).

Example code:

```
<script  runat="server">
Sub submit(Source As Object, e As EventArgs)
   button1.Text="You clicked me!"
End Sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:Button id="button1" Text="Click me!" runat="server" OnClick="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything you want. I would say you want to use ASP.NET (C# or VB) or PHP. Both are good for different reasons. If you have VS2008 installed I think even the templates there have a basic registration and login. Im going to guess you are using a database to remember users and so on?

I would recommend searching the web for tutorials on ASP or whatever you will be using. W3 Schools is pretty good to learn the basics.

On a basic form I made in ASP I have the form button submitting like.

```
<asp:Button ID="subform" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" />
```

and then the code behind it looks like.

```
Protected Sub subform_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles subform.Click

    insertform(name.Text, name2.Text, number.Text, number2.Text, blah.Text, other.Text)
    formtable.Visible = False
    MsgBox("Your form has been submitted! Form ID: " & dbquerymax() & "", 1, "Submitted ID: " & dbquerymax() & "")
End Sub
```

So the button is pressed and this code will run. It will use the function insertform() to put the data in my database. It then hides a `div` and pops up a message saying the form has been submitted.

That's pretty basic so I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your help. I actually am using W3schools for reference. I'm still having a hard time figuring this out. I studied Web Dev 3 years back so having a hard time recollecing stuff. I've already written my HTML code on notepad. After that I'm lost. I have a semi-functional website where the only thing missing is what needs to be done after the submit button is hit.

Comment: Well are you using ASP? Or PHP? and are you using a database? Notepad it not really going to help you. I recommend Dreamweaver for web starters.